# Handle single selected_indexchanged event of multiple combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm facing a problem while adding multiple combobox in a Winforms application programmatically. I'm assigning single event to all combobox at run time e.g.

```cs
combobox.SelectedIndexChanged += new Systtem.EventHandler(this.combobox_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Suppose there are 3 combobox has been added. Now the problem is when I'm changing the value of combobox1 same value will be set for rest two combobox itself.

Could you please help me on this!

Comment: It sounds like the problem could be inside the `combobox_SelectedIndexChanged` eventhandler. Can you include the code for this method?

Comment: There no code inside combobox_SelectedIndexChanged eventhandler.

Comment: Are there any other eventhandlers added to the comboboxes? Are you fetching the value from the comboboxes in your code? Are you setting the selected index for any of the comboxes in your code?

Comment: Or are the ComboBoxes bound to the same DataSource?

Comment: Yes, m using the same DataSource to bound all ComboBoxes.

Comment: Well, when you select an Item in a ComboBox (changing the current record), all other bound controls will follow. That's how binding works. No surprise there. You should describe what *the other ComboBoxes* should show when you select an Item.

Comment: When m select an item in a ComboBox other ComboBoxes are showing the same item. i.e. if I select "A" in first ComboBox the same item will be changed in other ComboBoxes.